# Cannot find file at '..\lib\fvm\bin\fvm.exe' error while installing FVM

Tags: flutter, dart, fvm

During the installation of FVM flutter, I ran the command **"dart pub global activate fvm"**, after which I tried to enter the command "**fvm list"**, but an error appeared - "Cannot find file at '..\lib\fvm\bin\fvm.exe' ( C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\fvm\bin\fvm.exe).This usually indicates a missing or moved file."[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ak1I1.png)

Added to path "C:\Users\Jester\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin"

Reinstalled fvm.