# Cannot find file at '..\lib\fvm\bin\fvm.exe' (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\fvm\bin\fvm.exe). This usually indicates a missing or moved file

Tags: flutter, fvm

When i run:
`flutter pub global list`
i get: fvm 2.4.1

but when i run fvm i get the error: Cannot find file at '..\lib\fvm\bin\fvm.exe' (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\fvm\bin\fvm.exe). This usually indicates a missing or moved file.

i have tried running some commands on the cmd:
`flutter pub cache clean flutter pub global deactivate fvm flutter pub global activate fvm`
still nothing works

Also when i locate the folder on the path above, the fvm\bin is empty

What could be the problem

Comment: This question is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76718894/cannot-find-file-at-lib-fvm-bin-fvm-exe-error-while-installing-fvm/76896582 and probably (as question includes same computer username) posted by the same user but with a different SO account !!

Answer (score 1):

The point is that you tried to install fvm in two ways:

- through `choco install fvm`
- through `dart pub global activate fvm`

Now what my recommendation is to remove your second option with:

```bash
dart pub global deactivate fvm
```

and try installing this package via `choco`. You will also need to add this location to the environment variables in `path` (or the location your fvm will install to):

```
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\fvm\bin\
```

Comment: instead of writing duplicate answers, you should redirect the user to the duplicate answer  as you already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/76896582/5882307 !

Comment: @OMiShah Okay, thank you. But this solution is an initial assumption and may go down a different branch of development in the future. So, save your exclamation points :)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to solve this is by removing the flutter environment variable before installing it.

Remove the `C/src/flutter` from the `Path`. And reinstall the fvm again.